# Get current Github Repository name with Octokit

Tags: angular, github, octokit, github-projects

I'm trying to get some information about the current Github Repo Projects, for a VsCode Extension, But I don't know (Haven't found it in the Documentation) how to get the current Repo name. With that information, I would try to execute the following (Which I got from the documentation & works when I hard code a rep name as a string).

```
return await octokit.rest.projects
  .listForRepo({
    owner: userInfo.data.login,
    repo: currentRepoName,
  });
```

Comment: what context information do you have with the VS Code extension from which you could derive the repository name?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, too :) 

When you say "current Repo", what do you mean? Current repository in the context of what exactly?

Comment: In the folder when you open a git repo/folder in VsCode. I’m playing around with creating an Vs ode extension which gets some information about the repo your working on.

Comment: Like the extension Git Lense, how does it know which repo it has to show the data from.

Comment: I can get the current folder, but the folder doesn't have to have the same name like a git repo (I think, or am I wrong?)

Comment: The source code for Git Lince is public, so you can check out how they are doing it? 
https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens

I'd assume the look into `.git/config` and use the configuration for `origin` in your git remotes

Comment: Yeah I was a bit dumb...I thought the hidden directories are shown in VsCode, but in the settigns of Vscode it exactly hides the .git directory. It was my first I idea to read it out of there but I thought it didn't exist xD. Now I read the file & with regex I get the repo name from the remote url (Maybe there's a better solution but it works for now). Thank you for making me look/think again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of [@Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206879/gregor) I got the following solution know. It's not quite pretty, so I'm still happy for any suggestions:

```
let file = await fs.readFileSync(require("path").resolve(__dirname, '../.git/config'), 'utf8');
let repo = (file.match('[^\/]+(\.git)')!)[0].toString().replace(".git", "");
```